# HOW TO TRANSPOSE ROWS DATA INTO COLUMN in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, transpose

**FIRST QUESTION**

I run this simple code to transpose row data into columns but it just show only the first data. Why does it happend?

```
SELECT  
id_material,    
at_part_number,    
mat_desc,   
GROUP_CONCAT(equipment_name SEPARATOR ', ') As Equipment`

FROM material 

INNER JOIN equipment_list ON material.id_material=equipment_list.PKid_material           
INNER JOIN equipment ON equipment_list.PKid_equipment=equipment.id_equipment;
```

And then how can I make the Equipment 1, Equipment 2, Equipmnet 3, ... column? Not by the SEPARATOR, but making some new columns?

```
--------------------------------------------------+    
| id_material | mat_part_number | Equipment    
+----------------------------------------------------+   
|     1000001 | AA111           | eq1, eq2, eq3 |  
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

**Second Question**

```
SELECT  
id_material,    
mat_part_number,   
mat_desc,`   
GROUP_CONCAT(equipment_name SEPARATOR ', ') As Equipment

FROM material 

INNER JOIN equipment_list ON material.id_material=equipment_list.PKid_material INNER JOIN equipment ON equipment_list.PKid_equipment=equipment.id_equipment;

UNION

SELECT  
id_material,    
alt_part_number,   
mat_desc,   
GROUP_CONCAT(equipment_name SEPARATOR ', ') As Equipment 

FROM material 

INNER JOIN equipment_list ON material.id_material=equipment_list.PKid_material    
INNER JOIN equipment ON equipment_list.PKid_equipment=equipment.id_equipment      
INNER JOIN alternatif_list ONmaterial.id_material=alternatif_list.PKid_material    
INNER JOIN alternatif ON alternatif.id_alternatif=alternatif_list.PKid_alternatif

ORDER BY
id_material asc;
```

Note : Material is the parent table, material table and equipment table has the many to many relation, and so the material table and alternatif table. 1 Material can consist 2 Equipment, 2 Alternatif (Material's Equipment equal to Alternatif's Equipment)

I want to make this

```
`---------------------------------------------------------------------------`   
`id_material | part_number | equipment (1) | equipment (2) | equipment (n) |`     
`---------------------------------------------------------------------------`  
`100001 | AA111 | nameeq1 |nameeq2 |`    
`100001 | AA112 | nameeq1 |nameeq2 |`    //alternatif part_number    
`100002 | AA222 | nameeq3 |    |`    
`100002 | AA221 | nameeq3 |    |`      //alternatif part_number       
`100003 | AA333 | nameeq4 |nameeq5    |`          
`100003 | AA331 | nameeq4 |nameeq5    |`     //alternatif part_number
```

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code if that's available

Comment: Group_concat is an aggregation function you need a group by clause. If you want separate columns you need dynamic sql and should search for mysql rows to columns.

Comment: i just read about it and i dont understand...

Comment: Asking more than one question in a post is discouraged; if you want to ask two questions, make two separate posts.

Answer (score 0):

Given this much simplified data

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE T (ID INT,col1 varchar(3));

insert into t values (1,'aaa'),(1,'bbb'),(2,'aaa'),(3,'aaa'),(3,'bbb'),(3,'ccc');
```

If you group_concat without a group by

```
select id,group_concat(col1)
from t;
```

you get this

```
+------+-------------------------+
| id   | group_concat(col1)      |
+------+-------------------------+
|    1 | aaa,bbb,aaa,aaa,bbb,ccc |
+------+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

With group by

```
select id,group_concat(col1)
from t
group by id;
```

you get this

```
+------+--------------------+
| id   | group_concat(col1) |
+------+--------------------+
|    1 | aaa,bbb            |
|    2 | aaa                |
|    3 | aaa,bbb,ccc        |
+------+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you want separate columns and have a known limited number of values you could use conditional aggregation

```
select id,
         max(case when col1 = 'aaa' then col1 else '' end) as first,
         max(case when col1 = 'bbb' then col1 else '' end) as second,
         max(case when col1 = 'ccc' then col1 else '' end) as third
from t
group by id;
```

to get this

```
+------+-------+--------+-------+
| id   | first | second | third |
+------+-------+--------+-------+
|    1 | aaa   | bbb    |       |
|    2 | aaa   |        |       |
|    3 | aaa   | bbb    | ccc   |
+------+-------+--------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you don't know the values or they are subject to change then you could build a sql statement and submit it to dynamic sql

```
set @sql = (
    select group_concat(concat('max(case when col1 = ', char(39),s.val,char(39),' then col1 else null end) as ', val))
    from
    (select distinct col1 as val from t order by col1) s
    )
;
set @sql = concat('select id,', @sql,' from t group by id;');   
prepare sqlstmt from @sql;
execute sqlstmt;
deallocate prepare sqlstmt;
```

which returns this

```
+------+------+------+------+
| id   | aaa  | bbb  | ccc  |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 | aaa  | bbb  | NULL |
|    2 | aaa  | NULL | NULL |
|    3 | aaa  | bbb  | ccc  |
+------+------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

If you want to limit the number of columns then using a variable to work out the maximum number of columns would look like this

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS T;
CREATE TABLE T (ID INT,col1 varchar(3));

insert into t values (1,'aaa'),(1,'bbb'),(2,'aaa'),(3,'aaa'),(3,'ddd'),(3,'eee');


set @sql = (
    select group_concat(distinct concat('max(case when s.rn = ', S.RN,' then col1 else null end) as Equipment_', S.RN))
    from
    (
        SELECT ID,
             IF(ID <> @P, @RN:=1,@RN:=@RN+1) RN,
            @P:=ID P
        FROM T
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @RN:=0,@P:=0) R
    ) S
    );

set @sql = concat('select id,', @sql,' from 
(
        SELECT ID,col1,
             IF(ID <> @P, @RN:=1,@RN:=@RN+1) RN,
            @P:=ID P
        FROM T
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @RN:=0,@P:=0) R
        order by id,col1
) S group by id;'); 

#SELECT @SQL;

prepare sqlstmt from @sql;
execute sqlstmt;
deallocate prepare sqlstmt;

+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| id   | Equipment_1 | Equipment_2 | Equipment_3 |
+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|    1 | aaa         | bbb         | NULL        |
|    2 | aaa         | NULL        | NULL        |
|    3 | aaa         | ddd         | eee         |
+------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: so the column of aaa, bbb, etc should be limited?

Comment: how if i want the column like this                                                            `id_material | part_number | equipment (1) | equipment (2) | equipment (n) |`     
`---------------------------------------------------------------------------`  
`100001 | AA111 | nameeq1 |nameeq2 |`    
`100001 | AA112 | nameeq1 |nameeq2 |`    //alternatif part_number    
`100002 | AA222 | nameeq3 |    |`    
`100002 | AA221 | nameeq3 |    |`      //alternatif part_number       
`100003 | AA333 | nameeq4 |nameeq5    |`          
`100003 | AA331 | nameeq4 |nameeq5    |`//alternatif part_number

Comment: I want the contents of the equipment is free

Comment: @Sheena Mulankova added

Comment: thankyou very much! But what is S.RN, RN, P, R? Whats the different between @RN, @P, @R?

Comment: rn is short for row number p is short for previous value - you should read up on mysql row number simulation. Or if you are on mysql 8 or above mysql window functions.

Comment: im sorry but i dont uderstand what these codes mean, can u help me?  `SELECT ID,`        
             `IF(ID <> @P, @RN:=1,@RN:=@RN+1) RN,`    
            `@P:=ID P`     
        `FROM T`      
        `CROSS JOIN (SELECT @RN:=0,@P:=0) R`